# Missing stack trace of crash report from external dependencies

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

## Description

Our project upload crash report to firebase crashlytics,
however stack trace of crash report from our external dependency of
our project is missing like the following.

**Crash Report**

[image: Crash Report]

I tried uploading the symbol file referring to the following site,
however it can not be solved.

[NDK Crash Reporting](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html#)

If you know, could you please tell me any solution?

When uploading the symbol file
The structure of the project is as follows

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── main
│   ├── build.gradle
│   :
│   └── ...
├── external
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── external.aar
│   ├── libs
│   ├── obj
│   :
│   └── ...
└── ...
    ├── ...
    :
    └── ...
```

crashlytics is set in the main project's build.gradle as follows.

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut '../external/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut '../external/libs'
}
```

`main` is refer `external` as follows.

```
dependencies {
    implementation_project(path: ":external", project: project, dependencies: dependencies)
    ...
}
```

The `build.gradle` of `external` is like the following.

```
configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('external.aar'))
task testClasses {}
```

In the external project obj and lib, .so files are stored as follows.

```
:
├── libs
│   ├── armeabi-v7a
│   │   ├── lib1.so
│   │   └── lib2.so
│   ├── arm64-v8a
│   │   ├── lib1.so
│   │   └── lib2.so
│   ├── x86
│   │   ├── lib1.so
│   │   └── lib2.so
│   └──  x86_64
│       ├── lib1.so
│       └── lib2.so
│ 
├── obj
│   ├── armeabi-v7a
│   │   ├── lib1.so
│   │   └── lib2.so
│   ├── arm64-v8a
│   │   ├── lib1.so
│   │   └── lib2.so
│   ├── x86
│   │   ├── lib1.so
│   │   └── lib2.so
│   └──  x86_64
│       ├── lib1.so
│       └── lib2.so
│ 
:
```

I uploaded a symbol file with the following command.

`./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbols{Variant}`

## Update:2018/04/18

**crashlytics.log**

when execute `./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbols{Variant}`

```
2018-04-18 16:53:48.325 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Invoked Crashlytics Developer Tools with arguments:
-androidOutputManifestDirectories /Users/<my_dir>/work/<project_root>/<main_project>/build/intermediates/manifests/full/<valiant_dir>
-injectableManifest true
-androidBaseManifest /Users/<my_dir>/work/<project_root>/<main_project>/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
-buildEvent true
-androidManifest /Users/<my_dir>/work/<project_root>/<main_project>/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
-apiSecret <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
-generateResourceFile true
-tool io.fabric.tools.gradle
-version 1.25.3
-properties /Users/<my_dir>/work/<project_root>/<main_project>/fabric.properties
-buildId <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
-targetResValueDir /Users/<my_dir>/work/<project_root>/<main_project>/build/generated/fabric/res/<valiant_dir>
-projectPath /Users/<my_dir>/work/<project_root>/<main_project>
-androidRes /Users/<my_dir>/work/<project_root>/<main_project>/src/main/res
-androidAssets /Users/<my_dir>/work/<project_root>/<main_project>/build/intermediates/assets/<valiant_dir>
-googleServicesResDir /Users/<my_dir>/work/<project_root>/<main_project>/build/generated/res/google-services/<valiant_dir>
2018-04-18 16:53:48.327 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Manifest and properties apiKey is empty. Looking for google_app_id
2018-04-18 16:53:48.328 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Google-services res dir: /Users/<my_dir>/work/<project_root>/<main_project>/build/generated/res/google-services/<valiant_dir>/values/values.xml
2018-04-18 16:53:48.328 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Found google_app_id: <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
2018-04-18 16:53:48.330 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - apiKey is <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
2018-04-18 16:53:48.330 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Generating crashlytics resources
2018-04-18 16:53:48.330 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Generating build info into assets folder: /Users/<my_dir>/work/<project_root>/<main_project>/build/intermediates/assets/<valiant_dir>
2018-04-18 16:53:48.330 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Updating build properties at: /Users/<my_dir>/work/<project_root>/<main_project>/build/intermediates/assets/<valiant_dir>/crashlytics-build.properties
2018-04-18 16:53:48.331 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Set build id to <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
2018-04-18 16:53:48.331 [DEBUG] (Build Event Notification) com.crashlytics  - Build Event: <application_id> ID:<XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX> ApiKey:<XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX> Tool:io.fabric.tools.gradle 1.25.3 Base Package Name:<package_name> Twitter Client Application Id:null API Secret Null? false Extra Details:[null]
2018-04-18 16:53:48.337 [DEBUG] (Build Event Notification) com.crashlytics  - REQUEST: https://api.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/android/apps/<application_id>/built
2018-04-18 16:53:49.654 [DEBUG] (Build Event Notification) com.crashlytics  - POST response: [reqId=<XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>] 200
```

Comment: Thanks! Are you using the external native build tool? Usually we like to do a sanity test of not setting NDK_OUT and LIBS_OUT.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
> Are you using the external native build tool?
->Yes, I use cmake to build external.
  (A output of external module is aar. The main is include it.)

>Usually we like to do a sanity test of not setting NDK_OUT and LIBS_OUT.
->I tried not setting theses param and get an error when execute `crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease` command like the following.
    Caused by: com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.codemapping.CodeMappingException: Crashlytics could not find NDK output directory 
  The stack trace of crash report is also missing...

Comment: Hmm, something funky is going on. Can you send over the following log?

On Linux / Windows:~/.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.logOn 

Mac:~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log

Comment: I update description(add`crashlytics.log` and the external project detail(build.gradle)). 
Could you please confirm it?
Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: did u solve your problem? please share the solution. I have the same issue.